# Элементы массива передать в другой массив

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Размерность массива: ");
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
        int[] index = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("index[{0}] = ",i);
            index[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        int [] array = new int [count];
        for (int i = 0; i <array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (count<=0)
            //Дальше что делать не понятно
        }
        
    }
```

> Создать массив размера N элементов, заполнить его произвольными целыми
> значениями (размер массива задает пользователь).

1. Выведите на экран.
2. Создайте целочисленную переменную count (задает пользователь), index
   (задает пользователь).
3. Создайте новый массив верните часть полученного в качестве аргумента
   массива начиная с позиции, указанной в аргументе index, размерностью,
   которая соответствует значению аргумента count.
4. Если аргумент count содержит значение больше, чем количество элементов,
   которые входят в выбираемую часть исходного массива (от указанного индекса
   index, до индекса последнего элемента), то при формировании нового массива
   размерностью в count, заполните единицами те элементы, которые не были
   скопированы из исходного массива.

Comment: И где у вас создание массива с произвольными числами? Я вижу ввод чисел с клавиатуры, а не заполнение случайными числами. Также я не понимаю, почему число index стало у вас вдруг массивом. Исправьте ошибки которые были уже сделаны - будет проще разобраться с третьим пунктом.

Comment: Спасибо, что указали мои ошибки, впредь постараюсь такое не повторять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы недостаточно внимательно читали задание. Читайте последовательно, примерно так:

> Создать массив размера N элементов, размер массива задает пользователь

```cs
Console.Write("Размерность массива: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] a = new int[n];
```

> заполнить его произвольными целыми значениями

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("a[{0}] = ", i);
    a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

> Выведите на экран.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(a[i] + ", ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

> Создайте целочисленную переменную count (задает пользователь), index (задает пользователь).

```cs
Console.Write("Количество элементов для выбора: ");
int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Индекс первого элемента: ");
int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

> Создайте новый массив верните часть полученного в качестве аргумента массива начиная с позиции, указанной в аргументе index, размерностью, которая соответствует значению аргумента count.

> Если аргумент count содержит значение больше, чем количество элементов, которые входят в выбираемую часть исходного массива (от указанного индекса index, до индекса последнего элемента), то при формировании нового массива размерностью в count, заполните единицами те элементы, которые не были скопированы из исходного массива.

```cs
int[] b = new int[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int j = i + index;
    if (j >= a.Length)
        b[i] = 1;
    else
        b[i] = a[j];
}
```

> Выведите на экран.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(b[i] + ", ");
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял свои ошибки, и как их решить.